# How do I delete an email in Gmail from the notification screen?

Tags: notifications, gmail, notification-bar, delete

The latest Gmail app update (26 MAR 2013) introduced a feature for devices running Android 4.1 (Jellybean) and higher wherein a user could directly archive/reply to an email from within the notification pull-down.

The "What's New" section on the Play Store however also lists the ability to delete an email.

> Android 4.1 (Jelly Bean) and up:
> • Reply, archive or delete from notifications - no need to open the app

I'm running CyanogenMod 10.1 (Android 4.2.2) on my Samsung Galaxy S2 (i9100) and the options for Archive and Reply show up when I pull down the individual email notification but nothing for Delete shows up, even while in Landscape mode.

Any ideas on how this can be implemented or a setting that I've missed to enable this functionality?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes - there is a setting you need to change.

The Notification bar's actions are based on what you have GMail set up to do when swiping away an email within the app.

To change it from `Archive`:

Open `Gmail` and go to `Settings` there change the `Swiping conversation list` from `Archive/unlabel/delete` to `Always delete`

This changed my Notification bar action from `Archive` to `Delete`

Comment: Just tried it on mine. As advertised.

Comment: Accepted. Unfortunately, the behaviour also causes conversation swiping within the app to equal deletion. I wish they'd fit 3 buttons like ARCHIVE / DELETE / REPLY (user-choosable ideally) within the pull-down of the notification.

Comment: Agreed. Also, within Gmail itself it should have options to assign left-swipe and right-swipe, that way you could swipe left to archive, right to delete (or the other way). Maybe next update...

Comment: Works on Android 9 (Pie) as well!

Answer (score 1):

**[Since v8.4.x](https://www.androidauthority.com/gmail-swipe-actions-customization-874334/), Gmail has been providing a separate setting to change the notification action** and reworded "Gmail notification action" to "Default notification action."

The setting can be accessed by:

1. Open the Gmail app
2. Tap the hamburger menu (3 horizontal lines icon) on the top-left corner
3. Select "Settings"
4. Select "General settings"
5. Select "Default email notification action"
6. Select between "Archive" or "Delete"